# Program Returning nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10

I saw this [Flowchart](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/images/000105.jpg) and decided to make a program out of it. The problem is, it only returns "Go Outside" if I enter "no" the first time. All others return "None". Im using Python 2.7

```
def waitawhile():
    print "Wait a while"
    rain2 = raw_input("Is it still raining?")
    if rain2.lower() == "no":
        return "Go Outside"
    elif rain2.lower() == "yes":
        waitawhile()
def Raining():
    print "Is it raining?"
    rain = raw_input()
    if rain.lower() == "no":
        return "Go Outside"
    elif rain.lower() == "yes":
        print "Have Umbrella?"
        umbrella = raw_input()
        if umbrella.lower == "yes":
            return "Go Outside"
        elif umbrella.lower() == "no":
            waitawhile()
print Raining()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your calls to `waitawhile` (from both `Raining` and from `waitawhile` itself).  After calling it, you're discarding the return value and returning nothing.  To fix it, change the calls from:

```
waitawhile()
```

to:

```
return waitawhile()
```

Make sure that, for both functions, there is no way to reach the end of the function without executing a `return` statement.

Comment: That did it! I also seemed to forgot a bracket in one of the umbrella.lower() statement. I wonder why that didn't return a syntax error.

Comment: @AnvitGarg It doesn't return a syntax error, because it is not an error! You just compared an object value with a string value, and it's ok :)

Comment: Yes, in Python if you refer to a function or method name by itself (without the trailing parentheses), you get the function or method object without that object being called.

Answer (score 0):

Your program have three problem, in the following they are fixed:

```
def waitawhile():
    print "Wait a while"
    rain2 = raw_input("Is it still raining?")
    if rain2.lower() == "no":
        return "Go Outside"
    elif rain2.lower() == "yes":
        return waitawhile()
def Raining():
    print "Is it raining?"
    rain = raw_input()
    if rain.lower() == "no":
        return "Go Outside"
    elif rain.lower() == "yes":
        print "Have Umbrella?"
        umbrella = raw_input()
        if umbrella.lower() == "yes":
            return "Go Outside"
        elif umbrella.lower() == "no":
            return waitawhile()
print Raining()
```

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Is it raining?
yes
Have Umbrella?
yes
Go Outside
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Is it raining?
yes
Have Umbrella?
no
Wait a while
Is it still raining?yes
Wait a while
Is it still raining?no
Go Outside
>>>
```

The problems in your program are logical error, so the interpreter will not show you a syntax error:

1. You used `.lower` instead of `.lower()` in the if condition, and it will be always false.
2. You ignored returns of `waitawhile()` method while you must return them to `print` method.